# How do I use optional protocol methods in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, chartboost

I'm still really new to Objective-C, but I've successfully created my own app and I'm having a little trouble implementing the video ads for Chartboost.

I'm implementing a reward video which creates a pop-up, offering the user a free life in exchange for watching a video.  I can get the pop-up working fine.  But I can't figure out how if the user has decided to watch the video or not.

I do know the Chartboost.h file has the proper method for this, listed under @optional, but I have no clue how to use this in my Level1.m file

```
 - (void)didClickRewardedVideo:(CBLocation)location;
```

Also note, that Chartboost.m is not included in the framework they've given me.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9018764/429427) & [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9018829/429427). It sounds like `Chartboost` is just a protocol (I presume there is no `@interface` in `Chartboost.h`?), which is why there is no corresponding '.m' file - protocols are just declared interfaces, not implementations. In which case you need to call `didClickRewardedVideo:` from the object that conforms to this protocol, after checking that the object implements that method.

Comment: Ok, I see - it is just a declared interface.  But I don't quite understand what you mean by "you need to call didClickRewardedVideo: from the object that conforms to this protocol, after checking that the object implements that method."  I read that question and answer you linked to, but I still don't quite understand.  I want to achieve this - if (didClickRewardedVideo) { then do this }.  Sorry - I'm still new!

Comment: Ah sorry, I think I've got it the wrong way around. I believe you want to implement that method in some class of your own that conforms to that protocol, and the library will call it at the appropriate time. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Chartboost library, but it sounds like `ChartboostDelegate` is a protocol that you need to implement in your own code, as with any delegate object. The library is going to call `didClickRewardedVideo:` on some registered object when the rewarded video is clicked. Have you set yourself as a delegate of a `Chartboost` instance, or similar?

So in your `Level1` class you must declare conformance to the protocol and implement the method (if you need to... it's optional after all):

```
@interface Level1 () <ChartboostDelegate>
@end

@implementation

// ...
// ...

- (void)didClickRewardedVideo:(CBLocation)location
{
    // Video was clicked. Do something appropriate.
}

@end
```

You can read more about the delegation pattern in Cocoa in the [Concepts in Objective-C Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11) documentation.

Comment: Hi Stuart, this is what I did based on your suggestion:  In my Level1.h file I did: `@interface Level1 : CCNode <CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate, ChartboostDelegate>
- (void)didClickRewardedVideo:(CBLocation)location;`  Then I implemented in my .m file `- (void)didClickRewardedVideo:(CBLocation)location
{
    CCLOG(@"I CLICKED IT");
}`
So when `[Chartboost showRewardedVideo:CBLocationGameOver];` is run and I click the video, I should see "I CLICKED IT", but I've still got nothing. @stuart

Comment: Also, there are 2 protocols in Chartboost.h  `@protocol ChartboostDelegate;` which contains `@interface Chartboost : NSObject`.  The second protocol is the one that contains didClickRewardedVideo and it looks like this: `@protocol ChartboostDelegate <NSObject>

@optional`  Maybe this helps?

Comment: Ah yes, I did expect the protocol to be called `ChartboostDelegate`. So the library defines a class `Chartboost`, which sends delegate callbacks to an object that registers itself as the delegate of `Chartboost` (under `@interface Chartboost` you will see a property called `delegate`). I suspect you're not setting the delegate, so are not receiving the callback. This is usually done where you create the `Chartboost` instance. Also, there is no need to declare `-didClickRewardedVideo:` in Level1.h - this is done implicitly by declaring conformance to `ChartboostDelegate`.

Comment: @Alan_s I strongly advise you to read the [documentation on the delegation pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11). This design pattern is pervasive throughout Cocoa frameworks & libraries, and you will encounter it time and time again. Download some sample code and try it out (e.g. anything with `UITableView`s will use delegation).

Comment: @Alan_s Oh, another thing: there is only one protocol in Chartboost.h. The first (`@protocol ChartboostDelegate;`) is a _forward declaration_, used because the actual protocol declaration (`@protocol ChartboostDelegate <NSObject>`...) is written _after_ the `Chartboost` interface. The interface needs to know of the existence of the delegate protocol, so the forward declaration says "there is a protocol called `ChartboostDelegate`, trust me", which is enough for the interface to declare a delegate property (e.g. `@property(nonatomic, weak) id <ChartboostDelegate> delegate;`).